# Is Synthetic Control Method a nonparametric estimator?

Tags: inference, nonparametric, weighted-regression, nonparametric-regression, synthetic-controls

I'm studying causal inference and I'm struggling to understand how to properly classify an estimator as nonparametric. My colleague argued that the Synthetic Control Method is an example of a nonparametric estimator. His point is that the inference in SCM is based on permutations and a rank. I argued that the SCM can be viewed as a weighted regression, as shown [here](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/15-Synthetic-Control.html).
My questions:

- What is the precise definition of a nonparametric estimator?
- Is the SCM nonparametric?

Comment: I think you are correct. It is definitely not based on "permutations and a rank", it is a constrained regression estimate (as you correctly said). Sure we can start making some "non-parametric" assertions if we start using non-parametric procedure to estimate the control and then perform non-parametric hypothesis tests but that's not implementation specific.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, you should tell your colleague that how the model is fitted (which defines whether it's parametric or not) is one thing, and how inference is carried out is another. One way to carry out inference in SCM are placebo tests, which involve permutations and rankings. But this has nothing to do with whether SCM are parametric or not.